# Truncate varbinary(max) column to a specified length

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I know that I can use the

```
UPDATE table SET column = .WRITE (expression, @offset, @length)
```

[idiom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx) to partially update a column of type `varbinary(max)`. However, I couldn't find documentation on how to set the length of an existing BLOB (i.e., how to truncate it).

Wild guess: `.WRITE (NULL, @offset, 0)` -- but, even if this works, is this documented?

**EDIT**: Note that I'm not interested in selecting a part of the data -- I need to set the length of the BLOB so that the next `SELECT` will return truncated data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of careful reading, I have found this passage in the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms177523.aspx):

> If *expression* is set to `NULL`, `@Length` is ignored, and the value in `column_name` is truncated at the specified `@Offset`.

The wild guess seems to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me in 2008 R2:

```
update MyTable set MyColumn = cast(left(MyColumn, 100000000) as varbinary(max))
```

The usage of binary data and large numbers seems to jive with the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx).

I'll update on faster methods if I find them.